# When using printf, newline makes string disappear

Tags: c

I am writing a program that takes an input file that consists of drawings of characters made up of hashtags (A, B, C...), reads a string from a console and prints out that string by drawing the characters according to the input file.

Note: As you will see below, the input file contains '.' instead of spaces. These are replaced with spaces in my code.

For some reason when I print a newline after a character is drawn, pieces of the character disappear.

I know it sounds complicated so I will provide all the file and the output below.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef struct{
    char znak[5][5 + 1];
} slovo;

void napuni(slovo *znakovi, FILE *ulaz);

int main(){
    int i,j;
    FILE *ulaz = fopen("ascii.in", "r");
    slovo *znakovi = calloc(27, sizeof(slovo));
    napuni(znakovi, ulaz);
    fclose(ulaz);
    FILE *izlaz = fopen("ascii.out", "w");
    char *tekst = calloc(50,sizeof(char));
    fgets(tekst,50,stdin);
    char *znak = strchr(tekst, '#');
    *znak = '\0';
    int duljina = strlen(tekst);
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < duljina; i++){
                int znak2 = toupper(tekst[i]) - 65;
                fprintf(izlaz, "%s", znakovi[znak2].znak[j]);
        }
        fprintf(izlaz,"\n");
    }
    fclose(izlaz);
    return 0;
}

void napuni(slovo *znakovi, FILE *ulaz){
    char redak[6];
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 27; i++){

        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            if (feof(ulaz)) break;
            fgets(redak,6,ulaz);
            if (redak[0] == '\n' || redak[0] == 32) continue;
            char *znak = strchr(redak, '.');
            while(znak != NULL){
                *znak = 32;
                znak = strchr(redak,'.');
            }
            strcpy(znakovi[i].znak[j], redak);
            printf("\n%s",znakovi[i].znak[j]); // this line prints the character to console for testing
        }
        printf("\n"); //when this line is uncommented pieces of the character disappear
    }
}
```

Here is the input file:

```
..#..
.#.#.
.###.
.#.#.
.#.#.

.##..
.#.#.
.##..
.#.#.
.##..

..#..
.#.#.
.#...
.#.#.
..#..

.##..
.#.#.
.#.#.
.#.#.
.##..

.###.
.#...
.##..
.#...
.###.

.###.
.#...
.##..
.#...
.#...

..#..
.#...
.#.##
.#..#
..##.

.#.#.
.#.#.
.###.
.#.#.
.#.#.

..#..
..#..
..#..
..#..
..#..

...#.
...#.
...#.
.#.#.
..#..

.#.#.
.#.#.
.##..
.#.#.
.#.#.

.#...
.#...
.#...
.#...
.###.

#...#
##.##
#.#.#
#...#
#...#

#..#.
##.#.
#.##.
#..#.
#..#.

..#..
.#.#.
.#.#.
.#.#.
..#..

.##..
.#.#.
.##..
.#...
.#...

..#..
.#.#.
.#.#.
.#.#.
..##.

.##..
.#.#.
.##..
.##..
.#.#.

..##.
.#...
.###.
...#.
.##..

.###.
..#..
..#..
..#..
..#..

.#.#.
.#.#.
.#.#.
.#.#.
.###.

.#.#.
.#.#.
.#.#.
.#.#.
..#..

#...#
#...#
#.#.#
#.#.#
.#.#.

#...#
.#.#.
..#..
.#.#.
#...#

.#.#.
.#.#.
.###.
...#.
..##.

.###.
...#.
..#..
.#...
.###.

..#..
.#.#.
...#.
..#..
..#..
```

Here is a test output (just printing out each character one at a time) when I don't insert a newline character in between:

```
  #
 # #
 ###
 # #
 # #
 ##
 # #
 ##
 # #
 ##
  #
 # #
 #
 # #
  #
 ##
 # #
 # #
 # #
 ##
 ###
 #
 ##
 #
 ###
 ###
 #
 ##
 #
 #
  #
 #
 # ##
 #  #
  ##
 # #
 # #
 ###
 # #
 # #
  #
  #
  #
  #
  #
   #
   #
   #
 # #
  #
 # #
 # #
 ##
 # #
 # #
 #
 #
 #
 #
 ###
#   #
## ##
# # #
#   #
#   #
#  #
## #
# ##
#  #
#  #
  #
 # #
 # #
 # #
  #
 ##
 # #
 ##
 #
 #
  #
 # #
 # #
 # #
  ##
 ##
```

As you can see it behaves as expected. However if I insert a newline character in between, the characters get mangled up. See below:

```
  #
 # #
 ###
 # #

 # #
 ##
 # #

 ##
 # #
 ##

  #
 # #
 #

 # #
  #
 ##

 # #
 # #
 # #
 ##

 ###
 #
 ##

 #
 ###
 ###

 #
 ##
 #

 #
  #
 #

 # ##
 #  #
  ##

 # #
 # #
 ###
 # #

 # #
  #
  #

  #
  #
  #

   #
   #
   #

 # #
  #
 # #

 # #
 ##
 # #
 # #

 #
 #
 #

 #
 ###
#   #

## ##
# # #
#   #

#   #
#  #
## #

# ##
#  #
#  #

  #
 # #
 # #
 # #

  #
 ##
 # #

 ##
 #
 #

  #
 # #
 # #

 # #
  ##
 ##
```

That's basically it. I am a beginner in C so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: Code in English - always! Pretty much every programmer understands it and if you don't anyone besides your countrymen will have a harder time understanding your code. (I'm German and I hate seeing German code!)

Comment: You're right. I will do so in the future.

Comment: `redak[6] = '\0';` invokes UB. Remove it as `fgets` does the job automatically.

Comment: @Cool Guy I did't know that. Thank you.However, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try `if (redak[0] == '\n' || redak[0] == 32) continue;` → `if (redak[0] == '\n' || redak[0] == 32) {j--; continue;}`

Comment: You should not be trying to access `redak[6]` at all, since you are indexing out of bounds.  The valid index range is 0 through 5 for a 6-element array.

Comment: @CoolGuy That just made it worse.

Comment: Maybe `for (j = 0; j < 7; j++){` → `for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){`. And BTW, what do you input for `fgets(tekst,50,stdin);`?

Comment: If that did not work, try changing `for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < duljina; i++){` to `for (i = 0; i < duljina; i++){ for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){`

Comment: In `napuni`, it looks like you're trying to read 27 groups of 7 rows each, skipping blank lines.  Two problems:  (1) `j` runs from 0 to 6, yet the first index of `znak` may only run from 0 to 4, so you are again indexing out of bounds, and (2) when you try to skip blank lines, with `continue`, you are leaving undefined values in the `znak` entry for those indices, which will cause problems later.

Comment: @CoolGuy It was a combination of your 2nd and 3rd comment that worked out. Post it as the answer if you want the credit. Thank you!

Comment: @terencehill I did. Its the second file in the list.

Comment: @user3779674 Note that your code will not display the question mark if the input isn't an alphabet. You need to use a `isalpha` for checking if it is a character.

Comment: @CoolGuy Yeah, I left that part for later. I didn't want to work on other problems in the code until this one was fixed. Again, I'd be happy to give you credit for the answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @user3779674 Yes, my bad! Sorry for the dummy request, I thought was only the output.

Answer (score 1):

You have a buffer overflow error in your code. You declare `redak` as:

```
char redak[6];
```

And then overwrite memory past the end of it with this line:

```
redak[6] = '\0';
```

The result is an undefined behavior. Note that tools like `valgrind` would help to catch this kind of errors easily.

Another problem is with your `for` loop: the condition should be `j<6` instead of 7.

Finally, `redak` should be of size 7 and the `fgets()` changed accordingly. Otherwise `fgets` does not read the newline character in, and so you start reading the "next" line from the wrong position. Remember that `fgets` reads maximally one less than size characters.

This all also means that `char znak[5][5 + 1]` should be changed to `char znak[6][7]`.

Comment: I have commented out that line but the output remains the same.

Comment: There are more problems than just this.  There are other array index errors.